# set colored-stats ignores $LS_COLORS

Tags: bash, ls, colors, autocomplete, macos

#### Problem

Bash `<tab>` autocompletion ignores `$LS_COLORS` variable and uses default color values.

#### Setting

I have a dircolors file and just the following declarations in .bashrc:

```
eval `dircolors $HOME/.config/bash/dircolors`

bind 'set colored-stats on'
bind 'set colored-completion-prefix on'

alias ls='ls --group-directories-first --color=auto'
```

The `ls` output is correctly colored by colors from `$LS_COLORS` and coloring for tab autocompletion is turned on. However tab autocompletion ignores `$LS_COLORS` and uses some default value (screenshot):

[image: screen]

#### Context

I am on macOS 13.2.1, using Apple Terminal. GNU bash (5.2.15) and GNU ls (9.1, coreutils) installed via macports.

#### Question

Interested in any pointers about how to start solving this isssue?
Maybe someone can point me to which source files determine the logic behind color-coding autocompletions in bash?
Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Autocompletion doesn't use colors for filetypes, just for directory, symlink, executable

Comment: @stoney I got the impression that it should, i.e. as described [HERE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File-Syntax.html#index-colored_002dstats). But besides that - even if it only colors directories, executables and links, the colors of `$LS_COLORS` are still ignored.

Comment: With file type the mean "directory", "+x set", "link", maybe suid set (didn't check that)

Comment: Try `dircolors --print-database`, there file types are stated as i wrote above. The other stuff is "file extensions"

Comment: You are probably right about this. But then, my issue still remains - why does it use defaults from `--print-database`, when I have `$LS_COLORS` set up.

Answer (score 1):

This is behavior implemented in the [GNU Readline Library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Readline parses `LS_COLORS` only when initializing the library and coloring is enabled, and not afterwards; if coloring is disabled when initializing Readline (after reading `inputrc`), `LS_COLORS` is ignored and Readline will use its default colors. To reproduce this issue I wrote this example C program, which you can compile with `-lreadline`.

`readline_test.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <readline/readline.h>

int readline_puts(void)
{
    char *in;

    if ((in = readline("> ")) != NULL) {
        puts(in);
        free(in);
    }

    return in != NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!readline_puts())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    // use coloring after Readline was initialized
    rl_variable_bind("colored-stats", "on");

    if (!readline_puts())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;
}
```

```bash
$ gcc readline_test.c -o readline_test -lreadline
$ mkfifo myfile1
$ touch myfile2
$ ./readline_test
> myfile<tab>
myfile1 myfile2
> myfile
myfile
> myfile<tab>
myfile1 (yellow, Readline default for pipes) myfile2 (normal)
```

But when setting `LS_COLORS` to display pipes in other color and changing `main` to:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // enable colors before Readline is initialized
    rl_variable_bind("colored-stats", "on");

    if (!readline_puts())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!readline_puts())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return 0;
}
```

```bash
$ gcc readline_test.c -o readline_test -lreadline
$ ./readline_test
> myfile<tab>
myfile1 (configured color) myfile2 (normal)
```

---

To take `LS_COLORS` into account in Bash you can enable colors in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
$if Bash
set colored-stats on
$endif
```

Note that updates to the `LS_COLORS` variable still won't affect Readline coloring, to update colors you have to restart Bash either opening another terminal session or using `exec /bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Something is definitely not working on my side. When I try to run your program everything is displayed without any colors (not even the colors that I see by default in bash). When I press enter within running your program I get: bind: Invalid command `colored-stats'.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius that's strange, maybe the `libreadline` found by the C compiler differs from the one used by Bash?